# Add to StackPanel DataTemplate instances programatically -WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

Let's say I have the WPF view in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingMatrix.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingMatrix"

    Title="All Learned Numbers" Height="500" Width="800">


    <Window.Resources>
        <!--Defining a dataTemplate-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type local:LearnedElement}">
        <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="Input:" Margin="8,6,-320,-164"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=InputTxt}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="300"/>
                <Label Content="Output:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OutputTxt}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="444,9,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="295"/>
                <DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"      Margin="44,66,0,0" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Focusable="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" IsEnabled="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  HeadersVisibility="None"/>
                <DataGrid Name="myDataGrid_Copy" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Margin="445,66,0,0" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Focusable="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" IsEnabled="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  HeadersVisibility="None"/>       
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Height="500" Width="800" Name="myGrid">
         <!--Place a dataTemplate instance in here, it will get the values from a list of elements -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableElements}">

    </ListBox>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

And I have the class to represent each item on the list of Observable collection.

```
public class LearnedElement 
{
      public string InputTxt {get; set;}
      public string OutputTxt {get; set;}
}
```

And I have the code-behind:

```
       //List of elements that will be binded with the template
       public ObservableCollection<LearnedElement> observableElements { get; set; }

        public Window2()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableElements = new ObservableCollection<LearnedElement>();

            LearnedElement learnedElem = new LearnedElement();
            learnedElem.InputTxt = "Example 1";
            learnedElem.OutputTxt = "Example 2";

            //How to create an instance of the template and add to the StackPanel ?

            LearnedElement learnedElem2 = new LearnedElement();
            learnedElem2.InputTxt = "Example 3";
            learnedElem2.OutputTxt = "Example 4";

            ObservableElements.Add(learnedElem);
            this.DataContext = ObservableElements;
        }
```

I would like to end-up with something similar to the drawn bellow, from a list of elements I would instantiate a new DataTemplate and place it on the StackPanel :
[image]

What is the best way to do it ?

**EDITED, but still not working:**

### Changed StackPanel to ListBox

Comment: Use ItemsControl - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes `ItemControl` is the way to go but be careful because `ItemControl` DOES NOT support Selection by default. You can however create your own `ItemControl` that implements `ISelectable`

Comment: You should set your `TargetType="{x:Type LearnedElement}"` on your `DataTemplate` OR put the template in the `StackPanel` template like so `<StackPanel.Template><DataTemplate><Label Content="Input:" Margin="8,6,-320,-164"/> ... </StackPanel.Template>`

Comment: @Franck "create your own ItemControl that implements ISelectable". What? Use a ListBox (which is an ItemsControl) when you need selection.

Comment: @Clemens Yes but it depends if he need the children wrapped in a container or not. `ListBox` will wrap but not `ItemControl`. `No Select -> ItemControl`, `Select + Wrap -> ListBox`, `Select + No Wrap -> ItemControl + ISelectable`

Comment: @Franck Both wrap their items in a control. ListBox uses ListBoxItem, ItemsControl uses ContentPresenter.

Comment: @Clemens I was referring to container wrapped. Either access from `ListBox>ListBoxItem>Item` or `ItemControl>Item` It's about how much overhead you like in the end. I always prefer use only what i need never more

Comment: @Franck You're confusing things here. While ListBox allows you to add ListBoxItems to its Items collection, you can as well add any other item data type (e.g. string) to the collection. ListBox then automatically creates a ListBoxItem for each item. You can still access the item by the type you've put in, e.g. `string item = listBox.Items[0] as string;`

Comment: Hey @Tito, it's usually best to add edits to the end of your question, rather than to change it as you did. Otherwise answers and comments that refer to the original question stop making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListBox` instead of the `StackPanel` and simply data bind your collection items to its `ItemsSource` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}" />
```

Then of course, you'd need to declare the `YourCollectionProperty` property:

```
// Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on this property:
public ObservableCollection<LearnedElement> YourCollectionProperty { get; set; }
```

Then finally, add your items straight into the collection property:

```
...
YourCollectionProperty.Add(local:learnedElem);
```

Each item that you add will appear in the `ListBox`. Oh and one last thing... declare your `DataTemplate` like this so that the Framework knows to use it when it sees your objects:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LearnedElement}"> 
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi @Sherindan, I changed a little your answer, there were some attributes that didn't exist, but is still not working, is not showing anything...

Comment: Thanks @Tito, but if you look, you'll see that the community rejected your edit... I'm guessing because you tried to change too much and added your own errors. It's always best to keep edit changes to just the necessary. I've fixed the errors myself now.